# Biological Electroreception/Electrogenesis (Electrolocation) In Air Medium

Tags: biology, science-fiction, genetic-engineering, electromagnetism, senses

So i got inspired by the electrolocation senses of some water animals that can be passive like sharks that only detect the electric signature of other animals, to active like electric eels that detects other animals disburbing it's own electric fields and i wanted to implement this sense in a character, but as water is a more conductive medium than air, how could electrolocation organ be engineered to work on air medium? Is that even possible?

(The question initially also pondered if such an organ could deted radio waves like an antenna, but then I realized that this would be no use in real life as radio signals are now digital and not analog)

Comment: Before I vote to close your question. (a) We are NOT a discussion forum. (b) You have NOT asked a question. (c) Designing from scratch an organ the permits electrolocation violates the BOOK RULE. (d) You are allowed to ask ONE question (biological vs cybernetic, two questions). *Please follow the rules of our Stack.* Ask one, specific question to overcome a problem you have with your efforts. Asking us to perform the entire act of creation is OUT OF SCOPE for the Stack. We will help you build your world. We will not build it for you.

Comment: 1. Just because there's not a question mark does not mean there's not a question here. 2. The OP never asked you to build a world. 3. The OP asked about designing a single organ. That's perfectly within scope here. I only see one question. 4. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Comment: @SurpriseDog Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a setting I'm designing, a race of genetically-engineered people have these sorts of "electroreceptor" organs. My design was basically just me spit balling and going by intuition, rather than doing any math.

The sensory system has two main components: a cerebral organ in/near the brain, acting as an interpreter of radio signals to the augmented brain; and the reception organ. The reception organ is an antenna, cruciform, running the length of the spine and branching out along the arms, with reciprocity so it can both send and receive signals.

The organ is made of conductive filaments like nerves. How the cells of the filaments detect and broadcast electric fields and radio waves doesn't really need to be elaborated on. Voltage across the filaments and current through them, with modulation.

The arrangement of two axes, down the spine and across the arms, covers vertical and horizontal polarizations. It's not necessary, but it reduces the signal attenuation. Signals experience shifts in polarization over transmission path regardless.

The genetic engineers programmed in a "language" common to all the modified. A machine language. The brain thinks something, and the cerebral organ parses/maps the thoughts to the common language, broadcasting them according to their intent (to a person, a machine, etc.), say, to another person. This other individual's antenna organ intercepts these encoded signals and their cerebral organ parses/interprets it for their specific neurological structure.
The cerebral organ needs to be highly-adaptive and sensitive to the larger brain. Adaptive, because everyone's neurological structure is unique, and sensitive, to achieve a high fidelity in interpreting one's own thoughts.
Machines can also intercept the encoded signals, as well as broadcast them back. The whole system is a mind-mind and mind-machine interface/network.

Answer (score 2):

A possible path may be what is known as [kirlian photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirlian_photography)

[image]

Though the mechanism requires contact to photograph, as far as I know, you may still be able to adapt the concept to your world, as it fits all other criteria.

Comment: Kirlian photography is a technique for creating contact print photographs. You have to place photographic film over a conducting plate and the object to image over that, then run a current through the object.

Comment: @BMF correct, as I mentioned above.  Granted I could have been more clear.